# Couchdb sync access with userid and password

Tags: javascript, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a couchdb running on a virtual linux machine. This db has cors enabled and setup. I have added an admin user and 
password to the db. I also have require_valid_user set to true.
I am trying to sync a pouchdb in a web page with the couchdb online with the code below. If I just pass the address 
for the db (1 below), I get a dialog box asking for a user and password. The sync works in this example.
If I try to pass the user name and password in the URL (as in 2 below), I get a sync error and the message 
"getCheckpoint rejected with ".
Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or another approach I should taking with this would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

P.S. I am able to browse to the URL with the user and password.

```
var remoteCouch = "http://192.168.1.7:5984/mydb";  //1
//var remoteCouch = "http://userid:password@192.168.1.7:5984/mydb"; //2
sync();

function sync() {
  var opts = {live: true};
  db.sync(remoteCouch,opts,syncError);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the exact same error message trying to sync to a couchDB on cloudant.com. For me, the solution was to use https:// instead of http:// in the URL of the remote server.
The format of the URL should be:

`https://<api_key>:<key_passwd>@<username>.cloudant.com/<db_name>`

So although I do not have a locally installed DB to test this, I suspect your error stems from the fact that couch redirects the request to a secure connection when you provide your credentials (scenario 1). While in scenario 2 no redirect occurs.