# Trouble with replicate with PouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I try to replicate a CouchDB database with PouchDB but I have a problem when I try the following:

```
var localdb = new PouchDB('namedb');

var remote = new PouchDB('https://example.com:6984/namedb');

var rep = PouchDB.replicate( remote, localdb,{
    live: true,
    retry: true
}).on('change', function (info) {
    // handle change
}).on('paused', function (err) {
    // replication paused (e.g. replication up to date, user went offline)
}).on('active', function () {
    // replicate resumed (e.g. new changes replicating, user went back online)
}).on('denied', function (err) {
    // a document failed to replicate (e.g. due to permissions)
}).on('complete', function (info) {
    // handle complete
}).on('error', function (err) {
    // handle error
});
```

The console says `:net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` and

```
Object {status: 0, name: "unknown", message: "getCheckpoint rejected with ", result: Object}
message
:
"getCheckpoint rejected with "
name
:
"unknown"
result
:
Object
status
:
0
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: Are you connecting to a secure server that use HTTPS?  You might want to watch [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780973/couchdb-sync-access-with-userid-and-password) similar problem.

Comment: Is that your actual PouchDB code? i.e. with no content for any of your handler functions?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem. The problem came from the version of erlang used by couchDB 1.6.1.
I have set up a reverse Nginx proxy and replication works in https